# Converting Double to String with multiple format specifiers

Tags: c#, .net, string, double, string-formatting

I'm trying to convert a `Double` to `String`, I need both round-tripping `R` and lowercase exponential notation enabled. I've looked at `NumberFormatInfo`, but it doesn't seem to define the exponent symbol.

I'm aware of `x.ToString("R").ToLower()`, but I prefer a direct approach if there is any.

The references I've examined:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
double value = 12345.6789;

//Roundtrip
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("R")); // Result: 12345.6789
//Lowercase "e" denotes lowercase exponent symbol
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("e")); // Result: 1.234568e+004
//Likewise uppercase "E" denotes uppercase exponent symbol
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("E")); // Result: 1.234568E+004  
//add precision after the "e"
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("e8")); // Result: 1.23456789e+004

//Variable Precision
int Precision = value.ToString("R").Replace(".", "").Length - 1;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("e" + Precision.ToString())); //Result: 1.23456789e+004
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#EFormatString

Comment: Neither of your second two examples round-trip correctly (you lose 2 digits of precision)

Comment: Updated for precision